# Is it possible to simplify expression in vector expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

Assume input as follows

```
in[1]=w = {a, b, c}; v = {d, e, g};
jMatrix = {{J1, 0, 0}, {0, J2, 0}, {0, 0, J3}};
ans= 1/2*jMatrix.Cross[v, w] + 1/2*(Cross[v, jMatrix.w] + Cross[w,jMatrix.v]) + jMatrix.Cross[w, v];
```

we have output[1]

> out[1]={-(1/2) (c e - b g) (j1 + j2 + j3), 1/2 (c d - a g) (j1 + j2 + j3), -(1/2) (b d - a e) (j1 + j2 + j3)}

Can i simplify the `out[1]` to vector crossproduct or dotproduct form(in other words, more  concise form.)?

`ans1 // Simplify` seems don't work.

Thanks @Carl Woll, `TensorReduce` works well, but it failed when i set jMatrix as $I_3$.

```
Clear["Global`*"]
ans1 = 1/2*jMatrix.Cross[v, w] + 
   1/2*(Cross[v, jMatrix.w] + Cross[w, jMatrix.v]) + 
   jMatrix.Cross[w, v];
TensorReduce[ans1, 
 Assumptions -> (v | w) \[Element] Vectors[3] && 
   jMatrix \[Element] IdentityMatrix[3]]//TeXForm
```

the result output not concise.

Comment: If mma can specify the form, and then to find the coefficient, if  expression don't match the hypothetical form,  only add some residual part....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you avoid using explicit vectors and matrices, you could use `TensorReduce`. Here is your expression:

```
ans=1/2*jMatrix.Cross[v,w]+1/2*(Cross[v,jMatrix.w]+Cross[w,jMatrix.v])+jMatrix.Cross[w,v];
ans //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{2} (v\times (\operatorname{jMatrix}.w)+w\times (\operatorname{jMatrix}.v))+\frac{\operatorname{jMatrix}.v\times
>    w}{2}+\operatorname{jMatrix}.w\times v$

And here is the result of [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce):

```
TensorReduce[
    ans,
    Assumptions -> (v|w) ∈ Vectors[3] && jMatrix ∈ Matrices[{3,3}]
] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{1}{2} v\times (\operatorname{jMatrix}.w)+\frac{1}{2} w\times (\operatorname{jMatrix}.v)-\frac{\operatorname{jMatrix}.v\times
>    w}{2}$

Slightly simpler than your original expression.

**Addendum**

The OP asked about setting `jMatrix` to `IdentityMatrix[3]`. For this you could use my `TensorSimplify` paclet. Install the paclet with:

```
PacletInstall[
    "TensorSimplify", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/TensorSimplify/master"
]
```

Once installed, you can load the package with:

```
<<TensorSimplify`
```

Then, the following does the simplification you want:

```
$Assumptions = (v|w) ∈ Vectors[3];

TensorSimplify[ans1 /. jMatrix -> Inactive[IdentityMatrix][3]] //TeXForm
```

> $\frac{w\times v}{2}$

Comment: Let me try, if i find some  technology, i will update this question, thank you for your patience.@Carl Woll

Comment: Amazing!  thank you again@Carl Woll

Comment: good job! @Carl Woll

Answer (score 2):

Also

```
ClearAll[w, v, jMatrix]
Inactivate[1/2  jMatrix . Cross[v, w] + 1/2 (Cross[v, jMatrix . w] + 
 Cross[w, jMatrix . v]) + jMatrix . Cross[w, v], Cross|Dot]
```

> $\frac {1} {2} (v\times (\text {jMatrix}.w) + 
> w \times (\text {jMatrix}.v)) + \frac {\text {jMatrix}.v\times w} {2} + \text {jMatrix}.w\times v$

Comment: it can works, thank you!  @kglr

Comment: @Ben, my pleasure.